# does kafka has any inbuilt flow control mechanism

Tags: apache-kafka

If producer is producing messages at a higher rate than the rate at which the broker can process? Does kafka has any other mechanism for flow control apart from the tcp/ip it leverages on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kafka [Quota](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotas) feature to limit the amount of data that can be pushed from a client to the broker.